# App get crashed after hour in nougat android

Tags: android, chromium

**Crash Log:**

```
    E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(173)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x3003
E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(173)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x3003
E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(173)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x3003
 W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
 W/google-breakpad: 1.1
 W/google-breakpad: 1
 W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
05-06 11:51:24.262 31906-31995 A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0x9009a6e6 in tid 31995 (Chrome_InProcRe)[ 05-06 11:51:24.267  2660: 2660 W/         ]
                                                          debuggerd: handling request: pid=31906 uid=10687 gid=10687 tid=31995
05-06 11:51:24.478 8869-8869/? A/DEBUG: pid: 31906, tid: 31995, name: Chrome_InProcRe  >>> 
ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.xxxxx/.MainActivity_kk>>>
```

Application is in webview all operation is performed in webview.. It working fine when is active but if we put it on for 1 hour it crashed automatically.

Comment: did you figure out any solution of above problem?